# MVC ViewModel not updating with Internet Explorer 11

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, internet-explorer-11, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have a simple form that is working just fine with Firefox 26 (latest version as of 12/26/2013) but when I run this form with Internet Explorer 11 I am not seeing the values from my two jQuery autocomplete controls being updated in my ViewModel.  All other controls are working just fine.  My autocomplete controls are of type  but I have several other  controls on the form that I have no issues with, just the autocomplete.  Are there any known issues with jQuery autocomplete in a ... rendered in IE 11?

I have also tested this with the latest Google Chrome and I have the same issue as IE 11.  This only works in Firefox :-(  I have no idea why.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when used IE, because IE cached my request so I did this:

```
$.ajax({
         type: 'GET',
         url: 'url',
         cache: false,
         success: function(response){
                   /* ... */
         }
});
```

Hope this can help to you.

Comment: You can send the current time, so with this IE have to create a new request.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Maybe this can help ypu to understand what I said  https://learntech.imsu.ox.ac.uk/blog/?p=266

Comment: thanks.  I tried this.  No difference for me.  Maybe I am having a different issue?  I get the data I expect with all browsers, but my ViewModel does not get updated with IE/Chrome, it does with Firefox.

Comment: there is too much to reproduce in jsfiddle.